How can I make France completely transparent in the map resulting from this code?
I'm using this code to create a map of Europe and I would like France to be completely invisible in some views, I wouldn't want to delete it from the list of countries. Changing the opacity does not change the result.
Basically I would like to change the opacity of individual countries.

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import kaleido
from plotly.graph_objs import layout

df_france = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["France"]
})

df_ukraine = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["Ukraine"]
})

df = pd.concat([df_france, df_ukraine], ignore_index=True)

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="country",
                    locationmode="country names",
                    color="country",
                    scope="europe")

fig.update_geos(
    resolution=50,
    fitbounds="locations",
    showcountries=False,
    countrycolor="#2d32aa"
    )

fig.update_layout(width=1920, height=1080)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}, showlegend=False)
fig.update_traces(selector=dict(country="Ukraine"), marker=dict(opacity=0.7))
fig.update_traces(selector=dict(location="France"), marker=dict(opacity=0.3))

fig.update_layout(margin={"l": 0, "b": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0})
fig.update_layout(width=1935, height=1840)

# Show the plot
fig.show()


Where is the definition for df_spain in your code?

@MohamadGhaithAlzin i'm sorry, there was a typo. fixed

Well, now I only get France colored in blue and Ukraine in red. Not as your image, why?

@MohamadGhaithAlzin It was another achievement. I corrected the map, now we see the same map

You are using the wrong selectors when calling .update_traces() method : country and location are not valid properties, but locations is (cf. Figure Reference: Choropleth Traces) :
fig.update_traces(selector=dict(locations=["Ukraine"]), marker=dict(opacity=0.7))
fig.update_traces(selector=dict(locations=["France"]), marker=dict(opacity=0.3))

If you want to completely ignore France on the map, that is, exclude it from the layout geo's fitbounds="locations" feature, which automatically zooms the map to show just the area of interest, use the visible property :
fig.update_traces(selector=dict(locations=["France"]), visible=False)

